# Play Framework 20 - Creating a form in the view

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I'm new to Play! 20 and I need to pass an object to a template and also a form of the same object, something like:

```
@(filter: Filter)(filterForm: Form[Filter])
```

I may be doing something wrong since this isn't DRY. Which would be the best way to access the filter methods and creating the form in the view related to this object?

Thanks

Comment: have you read https://github.com/playframework/Play20/wiki/ScalaFormHelpers ?

Comment: Well actually seems pretty dry for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to just use the `Form` object, since you can [get](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/2.0.4/scala/play/api/data/Form.html#get%3aT) the inner object from it if the form has no errors.

Something like this:

```
@if(!filterForm.hasErrors) {
    @defining(filterForm.get) { filter =>
      ...
    }
}
```